Question on circle and binomial coefficient
On a circle C, put n points on the circumference of C. Now the question says that ₙ is the number of chords (such that no 3 chords intersect at any one point), ₙ that of intersections of chords inside C, and ₙ that of region in the C bounded by an arc and/or some chord. Now the question asks few values of ₙ, ₙ, and ₙ where the value of n is the first 6 natural numbers.
I don't want answers to the question but a little explanation. I get most of the part of the question but how am I supposed to approach the question? I just completed the chapters Circles, Permutation and Combination, and binomial. But I do not have a clue how to solve this. I am preparing for the exam and unfortunately, this is how my preparation going on. There was not much time left for the exam to study everything in detail so I jumped directly on the previous years' questions.

The question is very clear for me. What exactly is your doubt?

@Gonçalo I understand the question but I still don't get it how to solve it.

These posts may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281359/question-on-circle-binomial-coefficient?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912480/number-of-points-of-intersections-no-of-parts-of-chords-inside-circle?rq=1.

@Gonçalo Your first link is almost the exact same as this question. Is this a possible duplicate?

@GSmith, I agree with you.

Thank you @Gonçalo, I got it. The answer in the other post to this question was confusing. Now things are clear to me.
